# how to convert a python slicing operation into java code

Tags: java, python, arrays, slice

I have this code line:

`x` and `k` are `int`.
`lm` is an array

```
lz=[f(x,lm[:j]+lm[j+1:],k) for j in range(n)]
```

My question is:

I want to convert the above line into Java...

I have created an `lm` array in Java, but I am thinking of making it an arraylist to avoid the problem of the array length.

I know that for instanse `lm` is `[1, 4, 1, 9]`. Then the output list will be:

```
[4, 1, 9],[1, 1, 9],[1, 4, 9],[1 ,4,1]
```

But I am a little bit confused about the way to implement it in Java ...
Any help is appreciated..

Thanks

Comment: My Python is weak, but wouldn't posting a full code example help?  Or are we just supposed to guess what the function `f(x,blah,k)` does?

Comment: it's just some function that takes three arguments, second one being an array, apparently. The result of the function for different parameters, as j loops from 0 to n, will be stored in lz.

Answer (score 0):

Will that help you?

```
  int[] lm = new int[] {1, 4, 1, 9};
    for (int i = 0; i < lm.length; i++) {
        int[] tmp = new int[lm.length - 1];
        System.arraycopy(lm, 0, tmp, 0, i);
        System.arraycopy(lm, i + 1, tmp, i, lm.length - i - 1);

        System.out.println("tmp = " + Arrays.toString(tmp));
     }
```

This of course doesn't use f() as I have no way of knowing what it actually does.